# OpenGL handling float color saturation ("color overflow")?

Tags: opengl, transparency, blending, color-blending, saturation-arithmetic

I'm woking on a scientific visualisation using openGL where I try to basically create a "coloured fog" to illustrate a multidimensional field. I want the hue of the color to represent the *direction* of the field and the luminosity of the color to correspond to the *intensity* of the field.

I use `GL_BLEND` with `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` to achieve additive blending of colors of the surfaces I create. The problem is: in some places the colors get saturated. For example:
*(1, 0, 0) + (1, 0, 0) = (2, 0, 0)*, and when this is rendered it just becomes *(1, 0, 0)* (i.e. the "overflow" is just chopped off). And this is not the way I would like it to be handled. I would like to handle the overflow by preserving hue and luminocity, i.e.

*(2, 0, 0)* should be translated into *(1, 0.5, 0.5)* (i.e. a lighter red, red with twice the luminocity of "pure" red).

Is there any way to achieve this (or something similar) with OpenGL?

Answer (score 2):

The output to the fragment shader will be clamped to [0, 1] if the image format of the destination buffer has a normalized format (e.g. UNSIGNED_BYTE). If you use a floating point format, then the output is not clamped. See [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) and [Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format).

It is tricky to blend the target buffer and a color, by a function which is not supported by blending. A possible solution may be to withe a shader program and to use the extension [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt).

Furthermore, the extension [KHR_blend_equation_advanced](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/KHR/KHR_blend_equation_advanced.txt) adds a number of "advanced" blending equations, like `HSL_HUE_KHR`, `HSL_SATURATION_KHR`, `HSL_COLOR_KHR` and `HSL_LUMINOSITY_KHR`.